# ActiveMQ slave broker accepts incoming connection from Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have the following configuration:

- Two actively running Tomcat instances running Apache Camel 2.20.2 that use the competing consumer concept to read message of the same JMS message queue
- ActiveMQ 5.15.0 in a master/slave configuration using a shared kahaDB

It happens that one of the Camel instances connects to the slave broker even though the slave broker is not active (i.e. as far as I can tell from the log files it did not get a lock on the kahaDB).

When this occurs the route on that Camel instance is blocked, and we get a `ExchangeTimedOutException` and this blocks the route and messages are being queued up.

```
WARN  EndpointMessageListener:213 - Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException - org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 30000 millis. Exchange[ID-MXPBMES-01P-I02-1625784159041-1-16108]]
```

Is it normal that a slave broker accepts a connection from a client application (Camel in our case)?

Comment: For posterity's sake, here's the [same question](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/activemq-users/202107.mbox/%3cCO6PR22MB262532E3C0E8588298D125C88EE89@CO6PR22MB2625.namprd22.prod.outlook.com%3e) on the ActiveMQ user mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

The secondary broker should not accept connections so this sounds like a bug, although you are not using the latest broker so before doing anything you should update to the latest release as there are always bug fixes going on.

Some issues can arise if the underlying file system does not provide a reliable locking mechanism which can lead to both primary and backup brokers becoming active.